# Upvotes and flags on locked post comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, upvotes, comment-flags, locked-posts

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c) locked for a reason which says:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed

To my surprise, buttons to upvote and flag comments are visible and active.

Upvote hasn't worked:

[image: attempt to upvote]

---

Flag has worked (it is shown in my flags history):

[image: attempt to flag]

I think there should not be buttons if upvotes and flags are not allowed. If they are, there should not be warning.

Comment: Maybe just dropping the "or flagging" would be sufficient here... Even though locked questions/answers/comments can't be edited/voted on they still need to be flagged in case action is required by a moderator...

Comment: @JonClements, maybe, I should say it separately `there should not be Upvote button if upvotes are not allowed. If they are, there should not be warning about them.`, `there should not be Flag button if flags are not allowed. If they are, there should not be warning about them.`. I'm uncertain about general policy here because answers don't have `Flag` option

Comment: @ASh Please don't use code formatting for content that is not code.

Comment: You can use `*some text*` to quote *some text*

Comment: @ASh Yes, your comment. You can use quotes `"`, bold, and italic to highlight non code text in comments.

Comment: ...still no updates

Answer (score 5):

According to [this post from Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229/237701), flagging a comment of a locked post is not blocked:

> A question or answer which is *locked* can no longer accept:
>
> - edits
> - up-votes, down-votes
> - comments, comment up-votes
> - new answers *<sup>(questions only)</sup>*
> - close votes, reopen votes *<sup>(questions only)</sup>*

It looks like locking a question doesn't imply that all the comments were checked/moderated. So it's totally possible that a post has been locked while it contained some *bad* comments. Blocking the ability of flagging comments may prevent the removing of these *bad* comments.

So it's probably the expected behaviour that you can still flag comments attached to a locked question.

The error message *This comment is not eligible for voting or flagging* should be changed to *This comment is not eligible for voting*.