# I successfully flagged a comment on a locked post!

Tags: discussion, bug, comment-flags, locked-posts, historical-lock

To clarify about a dupe: [Upvotes and flags on locked post comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322404/upvotes-and-flags-on-locked-post-comments)

It isn't a dupe. That question is mainly focusing on the part of removing the button, or warning. It's tagged as bug, but isn't actually speaking about the bug that you can flag it. It's speaking of the bug that the warning is appearing, and the buttons should be removed. I don't think this is a dupe of it.

---

I came across this locked post: [Hidden Features of C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538/hidden-features-of-c)

I was reading through the comments, when I by mistakenly clicked the flag icon. To my surprise, the flag dialog box appeared. I just randomly flagged the comment as "not constructive", to see if it will accept my flag. And yes, it did!

The flag was on the first comment of the question:

[image]

[image]

To cross check, I checked my flag history, and saw a pending flag on the comment:

[image]

I thought that flagging on locked posts wasn't allowed, as whenever I try to upvote a comment on a locked post, I receive a message dialog, which holds some text:

> The comment is not eligible for voting or flagging

This looks like a bug to me.

I'm using Chrome 41, on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

---

Repro Steps:

Choose a locked post. For example, the one I chose. Then:

- Choose any comment. Click on the flag icon. The Dialog appears.
- Choose any option, and flag the comment.
- Hover over the comment to see the red flag icon, showing that the comment has been flagged.
- To confirm, go and look at your pending comment flags.

**CAUTION:** Mostly your flag is gonna be declined, unless it really should be deleted. If you're on the verge of a flag ban, do not try this.

---

What? My flag got accepted! How could this happen? I don't think the comment was not constructive. Can a mod undelete the comment?

[image]

Comment: it's a hidden feature that one can flag comments on historically locked questions :)

Comment: Developers hate him, Look how he successfully flagged a comment on a locked post with a simple trick.

Comment: *I don't think the comment was not constructive.* why would you flag it then? SO is not a playground where you just click stuff for fun

Comment: @TimCastelijns As per the system, I should not be allowed to flag the comment. So I tried it, and nothing should have happened. But it happened,  which is not my mistake. Anyways, be happy. Now this action has turned out a bug.

Comment: If a lot of users follow the steps you mentioned and flag comments today, the mods will be happy :D

Comment: @Sunshine, You are not supposed to re-test a confirmed bug until it is fixed. Don't kill the system. :p

Comment: @Sunshine I'm bracing myself. Might even get suspended for making to many users raise false flags :P

Comment: [upvotes-and-flags-on-locked-post-comments question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322404/upvotes-and-flags-on-locked-post-comments). Ok, next time to draw attention to a bug, I {1} will use "Discussion" tag {2} add some hand-drawn circles.

Comment: I think the comment was not constructive and also it was kind of offensive. Quite funny though.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ `"making too many users raise false flags"` Is raising a [false flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_flag) when you use someone else's account to raise a flag? :)

Comment: @ASh My question is quite close, but isn't a dupe. I'll tell you how. That request buttons not to be there, if flagging is not allowed. Also, If it is allowed, it says the warning to be removed. It's main essence isn't the bug, it's about the warnings and the buttons. It would be better if you tagged the question with [feature-request]. In my opinion mine is not a dupe, but if you think it is, please provide a reason. I'll be happy to close it.

Comment: You should always be able to at least mod flag something.  IMHO the warning is the bug and not the flagging.

Comment: @NathanOliver You cannot mod flag on posts with historical locks. The one I've used is with a historical lock. See last line of this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post/22229#22229

Comment: Ah well look at that.  Then I am not sure which way is the bug.  I still think they should be flag-able.  Something rude or offensive might have slipped through and might need to be flagged.

Answer (score 13):

> I just randomly flagged the comment as "not constructive", to see if it will accept my flag. And yes, it did!

> I thought that flagging on locked posts wasn't allowed,

According to [this post from Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229/237701) flagging a comment is still possible:

> A question or answer which is *locked* can no longer accept:
>
> - edits
> - up-votes, down-votes
> - comments, comment up-votes
> - new answers *<sup>(questions only)</sup>*
> - close votes, reopen votes *<sup>(questions only)</sup>*

It looks like locking a question doesn't imply that all the comments were checked. So it's totally possible that a post is locked while some *bad* comments are still present.

So I think it's not a bug but a feature that you can still flag comments attached to a locked question.

---

But there is a contradiction between the error message *The comment is not eligible for voting or flagging* and the answer on Meta.

The warning should be corrected or the ability to flag should be removed in this specific case.

Comment: I think that there is a contradiction, as mentioned in your last line. If this is true, it means that the warning is wrong, and the warning is the bug. So let's see.